# why getchar() doesn't read the input?

Tags: c, input, getchar

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void){
    
    int character;
    double balance,amount;

    printf("Enter the balance: ");
    scanf("%lf",&balance);
    printf("Enter the transaction type: ");
    character = getchar();
    
    if(character == 'w' || character =='W'){
        
        printf("\nYou have selected to withdraw money");
        printf("\nEnter the amount: ");
        scanf("%lf",&amount);
        balance -=amount;
        printf("\nnew balalnce:%lf ",balance);
        
    }else if(character == 'd' || character =='D'){
        
        printf("\nYou have selected to deposit money");
        scanf("%lf",&amount);
        balance +=amount;
        printf("\nnew balalnce:%lf ",balance);
        
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to add any hint what input you provide, what output you get and what output you expect. In what way does the program not do what you want?

Comment: You should always check the return value of `scanf` to see if anything went wrong.